# VHDL synthesis error @E expecting a constant expression

Tags: variables, constants, slice

I have a problem while synthesizing the following code, I guess libero cannot accept variable in the slice range, How can I re-write the code so as to get the same functionality?

```
 process (r)
 variable c_offset :=  : integer range 0 to linesize - 1;
 variable counter : integer range 0 to AHBDW/8;
 counter := 0;

c_offset := to_integer(unsigned(r.haddr(OFFSET_R)));

for i in 0 to linesize - 1 loop
          if (i > (c_offset - 1)) and (i < (c_offset + size_vector_to_int(r.hsize))) then
            v.write_buffer(linesize * 8 - 8 * i - 1 downto linesize * 8 - 8 * (i + 1)) := hwdata(AHBDW - 8 * counter - 1 downto AHBDW - 8 * (counter + 1)); -- line where error occurs
            counter      := counter + 1;
            v.wb_mask(i) := '1';
          end if;
        end loop;
```

I think having variable counter in the slice range is causing the error. tried to use a separate for loop, but did not succeed.